# We’re getting right off the subject. (the function of 'right')

Tags: phrase-usage

> We’re getting **right** off the subject.

What's the role of the 'right'? Does it stress the meaning of the sentence?

Comment: It's an adverb functioning as a modifier in the structure of the preposition phrase "Right off the subject".

Answer (score 2):

> *We’re getting* [*right off the subject*]

"Right" is an adverb here.

It's a modifier in the structure of the bracketed preposition phrase.

Here, it metaphorically denotes exactitude of direction.

Answer (score 1):

It stresses the extent to which -- i.e. how far -- we are getting away from the initial subject. But specifically, it does that in such a way as to imply that we shouldn't be doing it!

So, yes, in that sense it emphasizes the meaning.

Answer (score 1):

- We're getting right or straight to the point.

COMPARE:

- We're completely **missing the point**.
- We're going off course here. [as in navigation, to be off course]

*right* means *straight*: *right to the point or subject* and that **means** **directly or exactly to the point or subject**.

*Generally*, when going off course as regards a topic, adjectives meaning precisely are not used.